# What's the path to iCloud drive shared Desktop folder?

Tags: terminal, path, icloud, desktop

I have an Xcode project and I work on it from 2 different computers (iMac & MBP). I use the iCloud Drive's shared Desktop option to temporary store the project and be accessible from both computers (it's just easier otherwise I'm constantly pushing and pulling data only for the sake to transfer the files from one computer to another (not actually having ready working code)).

The problem is that I need to set my default Terminal path to my project's path but I can't seem to find the path.

I tried (doesn't work):

```
~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Desktop /Users/<Username>/Desktop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it's much more simple than I thought. All I had to do is run

```
cd ~/Desktop/ProjectX
```